# Tab keep triggering jump backward in ultisnips

Tags: plugin-ultisnips, plugin-you-complete-me

I have a problem with UltiSnips. It keeps jump backwards even tough I didn't
map it in my `.vimrc` file. My `.vimrc` look like this

```
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<C-l>"                                             
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<C-k>"                                        
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<C-i>"

let g:ycm_key_list_select_completion = ['<Tab>', '<Down>']                       
let g:ycm_key_list_previous_completion = ['<S-Tab>', '<Up>']                     

let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = '<Tab>'
```

No there saying anything about `<Tab>` executing `JumpBackwardTrigger`. But,
when type this:

```
fpri                             \\ Then hit <tab>, it expands to:
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", str__);  \\ My cursor at __. YCM need to do the job
                                 \\ when I start typing. Then I hit <tab>
fprintf(stderr, "__\n", str);    \\ But it bring back!!
```

I have no mapping that involves `<tab>` key. So, what is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `<c-i>` and `<tab>` are parsed as the exact same key by most terminals. You can follow a discussion about this on this neovim issue: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/176

The easiest solution is to pick a different mapping for jumping backwards, like `<leader>i`. If you really want this fixed, I suggest following the linked issue and looking into leonerd's work.